# ReactJS - state not updated or has not effect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating so called recipe box, where you should be able to `add/edit/delete` recipes. Initial rendering part seems to be working fine, but I'm struggling when it comes to states and updating html depending what was changed: whether existing recipe was modified, deleted or new one added.

Currently I implemented state change trigger when recipe is edited. By reading various articles I came to conclusion that if you want to read values from another element when some other element is interacted (in my case from `input` element when `button` element is clicked), I need to add state to track input directly while it is typed and then use that state to trigger what I want (In my case I just use value from so called pending state and set to normal state when that button is pressed).

But it seems it is not working. Though I'm probably doing something wrong.

**Here is the part I implemented states I talked about:**

```
class RecipeComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: '',
            pendingTitle: '',
            ingredients: '',
            pendingIngredients: '',
        }
    }
    handleChange(e, key){
        let obj = {};
        obj[key] = e.target.value;
        this.setState(obj);
    }
    handleClick(){
        this.setState(
            {title: this.pendingTitle, ingredients: this.pendingIngredients});
    }
    _renderModal(target, ctx){
        return (
            <div className="modal fade" id={target} role="dialog">
                <div className="modal-dialog">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        <div className="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 className="modal-title">{ctx.title}</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-body">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="title" className="control-label"><span>Recipe</span></label>
                                <input type="text" id="title" className="form-control" placeholder="Recipe Name" defaultValue={ctx.recipeTitle ? ctx.recipeTitle : ''}
                                    onKeyUp={(e) => this.handleChange(e, 'pendingTitle')}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="ingredients" className="control-label"><span>Ingredients</span></label>
                                <input type="text" id="ingredients" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter Ingredients, separated by commas" defaultValue={ctx.ingredients ? ctx.ingredients : ''}
                                    onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, 'pendingIngredients')}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-footer">
{/*Seems to not update state properly*/}
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => this.handleClick()} data-dismiss="modal">{ctx.title}</button>
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
...
...
{/*Here title from state is never set*/}
    // Should this.state.title replace default title?
    recipeTitle: this.state.title || recipe.title,
}
```

Full code can be found here (you can also test how it is currently working if it was hard to understand what I meant. Try to open any recipe, edit it and press button `Edit Recipe` and nothing will happen, recipe title will not be changed): https://codepen.io/andriusl/pen/LjxYQo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You directly accessed `this.pendingTitle` instead of `this.state.pendingTitle`. so change this to

```
 handleClick(){
      this.setState(
            {title: this.state.pendingTitle, ingredients: this.state.pendingIngredients});
    }
```

and change this code to

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-target={anchor_target}
                            href={anchor_target} className="collapsed">{this.state.title||recipe.title}
```

Comment: For states, right I made mistake. I was not actually setting states at all at that point. Though I wonder why it is not working when I set `title` using state as argument for `this._renderModal`?

Comment: Disregard my comment above, I was looking in a wrong place. Everything seems to be OK:)

Comment: happy to help :)